# pecl install gnupg, could not extract the package.xml

Tags: pecl

I am having problems installing a package with pecl. My system runs Gentoo Linux. It does not accept the package that I am trying to install.

```
# pecl install gnupg
downloading gnupg-1.3.3.tgz ...
Starting to download gnupg-1.3.3.tgz (19,141 bytes)
......done: 19,141 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "/var/tmp/pear/gnupg-1.3.3.tgz"
Download of "pecl/gnupg" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/gnupg"
Download failed
install failed
```

The tarball looks fine and does indeed have a package.xml...

```
# tar -zxvf /var/tmp/pear/gnupg-1.3.3.tgz 
package.xml
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_oo_0001_import.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_oo_encrypt.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_oo_encryptsign.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_oo_export.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_oo_keyinfo.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_oo_listsignatures.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_oo_sign_clear.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_oo_sign_detach.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_oo_sign_detach_nonarmor.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_oo_sign_normal.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_oo_sign_normal_noarmor.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_oo_zzz_deletekey.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_res_0001_import.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_res_encrypt.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_res_encryptsign.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_res_export.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_res_keyinfo.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_res_listsignatures.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_res_sign_clear.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_res_sign_detach.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_res_sign_detach_nonarmor.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_res_sign_normal.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_res_sign_normal_noarmor.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/gnupg_res_zzz_deletekey.phpt
gnupg-1.3.3/tests/vars.inc
gnupg-1.3.3/config.m4
gnupg-1.3.3/EXPERIMENTAL
gnupg-1.3.3/gnupg.c
gnupg-1.3.3/gnupg_keylistiterator.c
gnupg-1.3.3/LICENSE
gnupg-1.3.3/php_gnupg.h
gnupg-1.3.3/php_gnupg_keylistiterator.h
gnupg-1.3.3/README
```

It would be good if someone could explain this better and help me fix it. Google results were very discouraging. It seems nobody else is having this problem.

I used to use the package in Gentoo portage dev-php/pecl-gnupg but that only supports 5.3. So I need to use pecl from now on to get the module for PHP 5.5. PHP 5.3 is now EOL.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how to manually install it...

After extracting the package, change to it's directory and run these commands...

```
phpize 
aclocal 
libtoolize --force 
autoheader 
autoconf 
./configure 
make 
sudo make install
```